# VB.net PrintDocument to PDF and send by email

Tags: vb.net, gmail

So i want to make a program that print a document as a pdf and send it by email
i have 3 document that i want to print and send
so firstly i make a document and print it like this

```
    Dim PageSetup As New PageSettings
    PageSetup.PaperSize = New PaperSize("A4", 827, 1169)
    PageSetup.Margins = New Margins(50, 50, 100, 100)

    PD_Income_Statement.DefaultPageSettings = PageSetup

    With PD_Income_Statement.PrinterSettings
        .PrinterName = "Microsoft Print to PDF"
        .PrintToFile = True
        .PrintFileName = "Reports\IncomeStatement\RPTIS" & Format(Now, "ddMMyy") & ".pdf"
    End With

    If System.IO.File.Exists("Reports\IncomeStatement\RPTIS" & Format(Now, "ddMMyy") & ".pdf") Then
        System.IO.File.Delete("Reports\IncomeStatement\RPTIS" & Format(Now, "ddMMyy") & ".pdf")
    End If

    If Not System.IO.Directory.Exists("Reports\IncomeStatement") Then
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("Reports\IncomeStatement")
    End If

    PD_Income_Statement.Print()
```

this code goes for all 3 document with different name and path
and then i send it with this code

```
        e_mail.Attachments.Add(New Attachment("Reports\DailySales\RPTDS" & Format(Now, "ddMMyy") & ".pdf"))
        e_mail.Attachments.Add(New Attachment("Reports\MinimumStock\RPTMS" & Format(Now, "ddMMyy") & ".pdf"))
        e_mail.Attachments.Add(New Attachment("Reports\IncomeStatement\RPTIS" & Format(Now, "ddMMyy") & ".pdf"))

        smtp_server.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        smtp_server.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(My.Settings.Email, My.Settings.EmailPassword)
        smtp_server.Port = 587
        smtp_server.EnableSsl = True
        smtp_server.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"

        smtp_server.Send(e_mail)
        MsgBox("Sended!")
```

when i run the print code first, i checked all the document is printed as pdf at the right directory, and when i run the send code it goes swimmingly.

but when i run all the code in once, for some reasons it cannot find the last document.
error message says like 'cannot find file C:........'
then i copy the error url, paste on my browser, and boom! my document is there.
why?

i need help
thanks~

Comment: Probably find the printing hasn’t quite finished writing the files in time for the next steps.  Maybe put a sleep after the print command as a test,  if that helps maybe need to look at building a retry mechanism or something like a background worker to create files, then in completed even construct the email

Comment: @Hursey Thank you soo much, i finally realize that the PrintDocument.Print() method it to send the document to printer and not the whole printing process. So while the document is printing my code search for the file that is being printed. Now i need to find a way to check if the printing is done before continuing.

Comment: Few options in addition to what I’ve already mentioned.  There is a EndPrint event on the print document class you could handle, although might still have a delay before file is available.  You could check the file existing looping until it does, might need some mechanism to avoid infinite loop.  Possibly a combo.